# Android runs on what JAVA SDK version

Tags: android

I always get confused about this, what SDK version of Java does Android run on?
For example Android 2.3 and Android 4.0. What JAVA SDK they run (1.4,1.5..etc?
Please let me know  unless I am missing the concept completely

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, java 1.6 is the version used for all Android versions. Keep in mind there are some things not present, and some extras added, so really, it's more like its own branch.

Answer (score 10):

> I always get confused about this, what SDK version of Java does Android run on?

Technically, it runs on no "SDK version of Java". Android devices have the Dalvik VM for executing Dalvik bytecode, not a Java VM for executing Java bytecode.

The Android development tools will cross-compile Java bytecode into Dalvik bytecode when you build your Android app. Those tools support Java bytecode from Java 1.5 or 1.6. It definitely does not support older than 1.5, and I am not certain what all happens if you try Java 7.

Comment: Thanks for the Dalvik explanation but I was looking for the java version to know where to look for description of methods as android development pages are very brief when it come to explaining Java SDK methods